# What causes disabled site URL under og:title when pasting links into wall status?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph

Sometimes, when pasting links onto a facebook wall the site name under the og:title is a link, and sometimes it's gray text. There is a similar unanswered question speaking to the same issue: [Facebook share 'clickable' url-link issue](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8443255/facebook-share-clickable-url-link-issue)

Here is an example screenshot: http://www.smartnet7.com/fb.png

Does anyone know what causes this to be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page being shared includes WWW, it's linked. If not, it isn't linked. Not sure why but that's what I've seen.